# ERROR: dump failed because resource AndroidManifest.xml not found Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: The command failed

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am getting this error when starting the app.

```
**Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
ziparchive W 10-03 01:27:24  3804  9104 Unable to open 'T:\batí\Mail\projects\wazaif_widget\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk': Illegal byte sequence
zipro W 10-03 01:27:24  3804  9104 Error opening archive T:\batí\Mail\projects\wazaif_widget\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: I/O error
ERROR: dump failed because resource AndroidManifest.xml not found
Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: The command failed
  Command: C:\Users\cordt\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3\aapt dump xmltree T:\batí\Mail\projects\wazaif_widget\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml.
Exception: Problem building Android application: see above error(s).
Exited (sigterm)**
```

I have tried everything but still couldn't solve the problem.